# How to calculate the accuracy of a Neural Network model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

In this case, I have a credit card transactions' `dataset` including 284807 records labeled as fraud or normal transaction each (the variable 'Class' represents the label of the transaction). Well, here I'm using `tensorflow` in python in order to implement a `Multi-layer Perceptron` (following an opensource tutorial that i found online) in order to build a binary classifier to predict if a certain transaction is a possible fraud case or not. To do so, i split the data into a training and validation sets by 70% 30% respectively. after running the model for only 10 epochs i got an accuracy of 99.8%!! which seems to be a non logical result for me. I had also recognized that the test set is not used while training it is only used at the end to calculate the accuracy. So could anyone please help me to understand what this accuracy represents here and how could i calculate the final accuracy of my model?

below is my code and the results.

```
import sys
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Choose device from cmd line. Options: gpu or cpu
device_name = sys.argv[1]  

if device_name == 'gpu':
    device_name = '/gpu:0'
else:
    device_name = '/cpu:0'

tf.device(device_name)
print('Device used:' + str(device_name))

datasetCSVPath = sys.argv[2]
parentPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(datasetCSVPath, os.pardir))
print(datasetCSVPath)
print(parentPath)

print('Reading dataset...')
df = pd.read_csv(datasetCSVPath, index_col=False)

print('Adding Class inverse column...')
clsInv = [ 1 - row.Class for index, row in df.iterrows() ]
df = df.assign(classInverse = clsInv)
print('')

print('Raw Data: \n------------------------------ \n')
print(df.head())
print('')
print('Whole dataset size: ' + str(len(df)))
print('')
print('Data Discription\n------------------------------ \n')
print(df.describe())
print('')

X = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['Time','V1','V2','V3','V4','V5','V6','V7','V8','V9','V10','V11','V12','V13','V14','V15','V16','V17','V18','V19','V20','V21','V22','V23','V24','V25','V26','V27','V28','Amount'])
print('Features Vector:\n------------------------------ \n')
print(X.head())
print('')

Y = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['Class','classInverse'])
print('Class Vector:\n------------------------------ \n')
print(Y.head())
print('')


print('Splitting Features and Class vectors into training and validation sets by 70/30 ratio...')
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.3)
print('Train features set size: ' + str(len(X_train)))
print('Train Class size: ' + str(len(Y_train)))
print('Test features size: ' + str(len(X_test)))
print('Test Class size: ' + str(len(Y_test)))


# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 10
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1


# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 10 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 10 # 2nd layer number of features
n_input = 30 # Number of feature
n_classes = 2 # Number of classes to predict


# tf Graph input
# x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [101, n_input])
# y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=pred, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Implement get_GPU_tensorflow_session method, to use CPU just return tf.Session() instead
def get_session():
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    return tf.Session(config=config)

print('')   
startTime = datetime.now()
print("Started at: ", startTime)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Launch the graph
with get_session() as sess:
    #sess.run(init)
    saver.restore(sess, parentPath + "/model.ckpt")
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(len(X_train)/batch_size)
        X_batches = np.array_split(X_train, total_batch)
        Y_batches = np.array_split(Y_train, total_batch)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = X_batches[i], Y_batches[i]
            #print(batch_x)
            #print(batch_y)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    save_path = saver.save(sess, parentPath + "/model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float" ))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: X_test, y: Y_test}))
    print("Time taken:", datetime.now() - startTime)
    global result 
    result = tf.argmax(pred, 1).eval({x: X_test, y: Y_test})
```

Here is the output:

```
C:\Users\MOHAMMAD>python C:\Users\MOHAMMAD\Documents\Fraud\CreditCard\Trained.py cpu C:\Users\MOHAMMAD\Documents\Fraud\CreditCard\CC_All.csv
Device used:/cpu:0
C:\Users\MOHAMMAD\Documents\Fraud\CreditCard\CC_All.csv
C:\Users\MOHAMMAD\Documents\Fraud\CreditCard
Reading dataset...
Adding Class inverse column...

Raw Data:
------------------------------

   Unnamed: 0  Time        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5  \
0           1   0.0 -1.359807 -0.072781  2.536347  1.378155 -0.338321
1           2   0.0  1.191857  0.266151  0.166480  0.448154  0.060018
2           3   1.0 -1.358354 -1.340163  1.773209  0.379780 -0.503198
3           4   1.0 -0.966272 -0.185226  1.792993 -0.863291 -0.010309
4           5   2.0 -1.158233  0.877737  1.548718  0.403034 -0.407193

         V6        V7        V8      ...            V22       V23       V24  \
0  0.462388  0.239599  0.098698      ...       0.277838 -0.110474  0.066928
1 -0.082361 -0.078803  0.085102      ...      -0.638672  0.101288 -0.339846
2  1.800499  0.791461  0.247676      ...       0.771679  0.909412 -0.689281
3  1.247203  0.237609  0.377436      ...       0.005274 -0.190321 -1.175575
4  0.095921  0.592941 -0.270533      ...       0.798278 -0.137458  0.141267

        V25       V26       V27       V28  Amount  Class  classInverse
0  0.128539 -0.189115  0.133558 -0.021053  149.62      0           1.0
1  0.167170  0.125895 -0.008983  0.014724    2.69      0           1.0
2 -0.327642 -0.139097 -0.055353 -0.059752  378.66      0           1.0
3  0.647376 -0.221929  0.062723  0.061458  123.50      0           1.0
4 -0.206010  0.502292  0.219422  0.215153   69.99      0           1.0

[5 rows x 33 columns]

Whole dataset size: 284807

Data Discription
------------------------------

          Unnamed: 0           Time            V1            V2            V3  \
count  284807.000000  284807.000000  2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05
mean   142404.000000   94813.859575  1.165980e-15  3.416908e-16 -1.373150e-15
std     82216.843396   47488.145955  1.958696e+00  1.651309e+00  1.516255e+00
min         1.000000       0.000000 -5.640751e+01 -7.271573e+01 -4.832559e+01
25%     71202.500000   54201.500000 -9.203734e-01 -5.985499e-01 -8.903648e-01
50%    142404.000000   84692.000000  1.810880e-02  6.548556e-02  1.798463e-01
75%    213605.500000  139320.500000  1.315642e+00  8.037239e-01  1.027196e+00
max    284807.000000  172792.000000  2.454930e+00  2.205773e+01  9.382558e+00

                 V4            V5            V6            V7            V8  \
count  2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05
mean   2.086869e-15  9.604066e-16  1.490107e-15 -5.556467e-16  1.177556e-16
std    1.415869e+00  1.380247e+00  1.332271e+00  1.237094e+00  1.194353e+00
min   -5.683171e+00 -1.137433e+02 -2.616051e+01 -4.355724e+01 -7.321672e+01
25%   -8.486401e-01 -6.915971e-01 -7.682956e-01 -5.540759e-01 -2.086297e-01
50%   -1.984653e-02 -5.433583e-02 -2.741871e-01  4.010308e-02  2.235804e-02
75%    7.433413e-01  6.119264e-01  3.985649e-01  5.704361e-01  3.273459e-01
max    1.687534e+01  3.480167e+01  7.330163e+01  1.205895e+02  2.000721e+01

           ...                 V22           V23           V24           V25  \
count      ...        2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05
mean       ...       -3.444850e-16  2.578648e-16  4.471968e-15  5.340915e-16
std        ...        7.257016e-01  6.244603e-01  6.056471e-01  5.212781e-01
min        ...       -1.093314e+01 -4.480774e+01 -2.836627e+00 -1.029540e+01
25%        ...       -5.423504e-01 -1.618463e-01 -3.545861e-01 -3.171451e-01
50%        ...        6.781943e-03 -1.119293e-02  4.097606e-02  1.659350e-02
75%        ...        5.285536e-01  1.476421e-01  4.395266e-01  3.507156e-01
max        ...        1.050309e+01  2.252841e+01  4.584549e+00  7.519589e+00

                V26           V27           V28         Amount          Class  \
count  2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05  2.848070e+05  284807.000000  284807.000000
mean   1.687098e-15 -3.666453e-16 -1.220404e-16      88.349619       0.001727
std    4.822270e-01  4.036325e-01  3.300833e-01     250.120109       0.041527
min   -2.604551e+00 -2.256568e+01 -1.543008e+01       0.000000       0.000000
25%   -3.269839e-01 -7.083953e-02 -5.295979e-02       5.600000       0.000000
50%   -5.213911e-02  1.342146e-03  1.124383e-02      22.000000       0.000000
75%    2.409522e-01  9.104512e-02  7.827995e-02      77.165000       0.000000
max    3.517346e+00  3.161220e+01  3.384781e+01   25691.160000       1.000000

        classInverse
count  284807.000000
mean        0.998273
std         0.041527
min         0.000000
25%         1.000000
50%         1.000000
75%         1.000000
max         1.000000

[8 rows x 33 columns]

Features Vector:
------------------------------

   Time        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7  \
0   0.0 -1.359807 -0.072781  2.536347  1.378155 -0.338321  0.462388  0.239599
1   0.0  1.191857  0.266151  0.166480  0.448154  0.060018 -0.082361 -0.078803
2   1.0 -1.358354 -1.340163  1.773209  0.379780 -0.503198  1.800499  0.791461
3   1.0 -0.966272 -0.185226  1.792993 -0.863291 -0.010309  1.247203  0.237609
4   2.0 -1.158233  0.877737  1.548718  0.403034 -0.407193  0.095921  0.592941

         V8        V9   ...         V20       V21       V22       V23  \
0  0.098698  0.363787   ...    0.251412 -0.018307  0.277838 -0.110474
1  0.085102 -0.255425   ...   -0.069083 -0.225775 -0.638672  0.101288
2  0.247676 -1.514654   ...    0.524980  0.247998  0.771679  0.909412
3  0.377436 -1.387024   ...   -0.208038 -0.108300  0.005274 -0.190321
4 -0.270533  0.817739   ...    0.408542 -0.009431  0.798278 -0.137458

        V24       V25       V26       V27       V28  Amount
0  0.066928  0.128539 -0.189115  0.133558 -0.021053  149.62
1 -0.339846  0.167170  0.125895 -0.008983  0.014724    2.69
2 -0.689281 -0.327642 -0.139097 -0.055353 -0.059752  378.66
3 -1.175575  0.647376 -0.221929  0.062723  0.061458  123.50
4  0.141267 -0.206010  0.502292  0.219422  0.215153   69.99

[5 rows x 30 columns]

Class Vector:
------------------------------

   Class  classInverse
0      0           1.0
1      0           1.0
2      0           1.0
3      0           1.0
4      0           1.0

Splitting Features and Class vectors into training and validation sets by 70/30 ratio...
Train features set size: 199364
Train Class size: 199364
Test features size: 85443
Test Class size: 85443

Started at:  2018-05-09 16:24:37.251806

Epoch: 0001 cost= 27.350340114
Epoch: 0002 cost= 35.998613088
Epoch: 0003 cost= 37.397314369
Epoch: 0004 cost= 16.843922048
Epoch: 0005 cost= 34.638866356
Epoch: 0006 cost= 49.155772096
Epoch: 0007 cost= 37.163821420
Epoch: 0008 cost= 39.222774566
Epoch: 0009 cost= 35.772652394
Epoch: 0010 cost= 31.369274977
Model saved in path: C:\Users\MOHAMMAD\Documents\Fraud\CreditCard/model.ckpt
Optimization Finished!
Accuracy: 0.99854875
Time taken: 0:00:32.633586
```

Sorry for any miss-representation of the issue since I'd just started to learn `tensorflow`. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: One useful thing to rationalize accuracy is to understand how many frauds you have over legit transactions. If your dataset is very imbalanced, e.g. with just 1 transaction being fraudulent every 999 legit ones, the classifier that always outputs "legit" is a 99.9% accurate baseline :)

Comment: yes that is true but what is the solution for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first analyse the distribution of your dataset because such normal-fraud datasets are usually highly imbalanced, meaning that they have disproportionately high number of normal cases compared to fraud cases. For example, if only 1% of the dataset represents fraud cases, then an accuracy of even 99% cannot be said to be good enough. In such cases, using precision and sensitivity is a better metric for accuracy.

In your case, it is important that you recognize all fraud cases correctly, even if you classify a few normal cases as fraud. For such a requirement, sensitivity is a good metric (sensitivity basically represents how good the model is at detecting positives/frauds).

Comment: thanks, this is a great answer but i have a question here, what is the best way to calculate the sensitivity? is there any specific algorithm that could help here?

Comment: sensitivity can be calculated using the confusion matrix of your predictions. A confusion matrix is basically a representation of your original distribution vs your predicted distribution. The sensitivity can then be calculated using a very simple formula on this matrix. You can learn about these in detail [here](https://uberpython.wordpress.com/2012/01/01/precision-recall-sensitivity-and-specificity/)